# redirect a http to https website in react

Tags: reactjs, http, https

I have hosted a website developed in `ReactJS`. Let's say `https://example.com/`. It is currently also accessible with `http`.
So I want to redirect to `https://example.com/` if someone access `http://example.com/`

Comment: It's not something to be done on the application side. It is the network side of things. It depends on what platform you use to host the website.

Comment: Can we access the full `url` and if `url` contains `http` then I should redirect to `https`. Can we do this in `index.js` ?